# Creating winrar volumes via command line

Tags: cmd, winrar

- I'm trying to create 500MB volumes using winrar via the command line interface (using cmd).  Despite a number of attempts I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

I have tried using the -v switch, like this:

> rar a -v500000k -m5 -ep archive_name file_names

When I run it, a single archive is produced that exceeds 500MB.

The help page says describes the switch behaviour as:

> v[k,b]  Create volumes with size=*1000 [*1024, *1]

I noticed that if I run it like this, 500kB volumes are produced as you would expect:

> rar a -v500k -m5 -ep archive_name

But if I try to produce 5MB volumes, as follows, a single archive is produced with a size greater than 5MB.

> rar a -v5000k -m5 -ep archive_name

I've tried running it as follows (and a number of other variations), but again an archive is produced that exceeds 500MB:

> rar a -v500m -m5 -ep archive_name

- Is there another switch I'm missing?
- Am I specifying the file size incorrectly?
- Or does the CLI for Winrar simply not support this?

Comment: The text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR* is the manual for console version `Rar.exe`. The command line `rar a -v500m -m5 -ep archive_name` should work and it works perfect in my test with `Rar.exe` version 5.70. The volumes `archive_name.part*.rar` have not more than 524.288.000 bytes which is exactly 500 [MiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mibibyte) which many computer users including author of *Rar/WinRAR* name MB. You would need `rar a -v500M -m5 -ep archive_name` to create volumes of 500 [MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte) with 500.000.000 bytes.

Comment: You might need additionally the switch `-cfg-` to ignore configuration file and RAR environment variable although this is usually not necessary, but recommended on creating RAR archives automated with a batch file or a shortcut file.

Comment: Solved.  The -cfg- flag enabled creation of volumes of the specified size.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To create 500MB volumes with WinRAR when running in a script, add the -cfg- flag to ignore the config file and RAR environment variable:

`rar a -cfg- -v500m -m5 -ep archive_name file_names`